# How to get "$" on termux terminal?

Tags: termux

I was using termux and suddenly after I restarted it "~$" appears instead of "$". Why did this happen and how can I get $ back on terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

- I think either you have set PS1 or accidentally changed your shell into fish. Basically you can set PS1 for getting "$" sign.
  `export PS1='$ '`   and add that in `~/.bash_profile` as well.
- if you accidentally changed your shell then get back in bash by `chsh`

- But what is wrong with that prompt, here ~ is showing current directory that is $HOME. When you change directory it will be also change.